# Sharepoint foundation-Need to show excel file contens within sharepoint page

Tags: excel-services, office-web-apps, xml-viewer-web-part

Scenario: Sharepoint foundation 2010.

End users would like to view the EXCEL documents within sharepoint page and not loosing the typical excel functionality.

The USERS would open EXCEL file (using EXCEL) and then save as XML. I should then provide an option to read this XML and show the excel within sharepoint. Don't know why USERS want to give me XML but if there is an option to directly link to EXCEL that's also fine.

I see office web-apps should be used? Does it work for Sharepoint foundation 2010? Please suggest the best options.

-Thanks.

Comment: For the OWA part, it should work on Foundation:  Business customers licensed for Microsoft Office 2010 through a Volume Licensing program can run Office Web Apps on a server running Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 or Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010.

Comment: @AndersAune:  thanks for the details. I am searching for any links to show to our management. Please share if you have any.

Comment: The information I pasted was from: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee815687.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement you should go with the Office Web Apps. I will also works fine with Sharepoint 2010 Foundation and you can also download it from volume licensing program of Microsoft.
Here is an post that shows system requirements of Web Apps.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431682.aspx

And these are the steps to install and configure the web apps on your sharepoint server.http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff431687(office.14).aspx

Note that if you have multiple server in the farm then you should install web apps on all server for load balancing.